# jQuery - Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

http://jsfiddle.net/bGDME/

Basically, I want to show only whatever is selected in the scope and hide the rest.

The way I did it seems so.. I don't know. Tedious.

I was hoping to get some ideas of making it better. A point in the right direction would be very much appreciated, too.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not add a class to hide elements that are out of your scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can minimize the code by using `toggle()` instead of your if/else statements

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/bGDME/1/

```
$('#scope').change( function(){
    var type = $('option:selected', this).val();
    $('#grade').toggle(type == 2 || type == 3);
    $('#class').toggle(type == 3);
});
```

---

> [**.toggle(showOrHide)**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)
>
> showOrHide: A Boolean indicating whether to show or hide the elements.

Comment: Nice. Simple and Clean. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

what about this??

```
  $(document).ready( function() {    
    $('#grade, #class').hide();    
    $('#scope').change( function(){    
        var type = $('option:selected', this).text();
        alert(type);      
        $('select').next().not('#'+type).hide();
        $('#'+type).show();       
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bGDME/13/)

Answer (score 0):

This seems fine to me, unless you have lots of or dynamic controls. However u can use JQuery `addClass` / `removeClass`, `switch` statement, multiple Selector  `$('#grade, #class').show();` to minimize the code

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a switch state: http://jsfiddle.net/bGDME/3/

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/bGDME/30/

You simply use the `val()` of the `scope` within the `eq()` method to determine which sibling `select` should remain shown. If 'school' is chosen from the first dropdown, then neither get shown:

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    var additionalSelects = $('#grade, #class');

    $('#scope').change(function(){
        var selectedVal = $(this).val();
        additionalSelects.hide();
        if(selectedVal > 1){
            additionalSelects.eq(selectedVal - 2).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: not really since I don't want to hide the `school` select box when I choose `grade`. etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using HTML5 data attributes to declaratively set "scope levels" on the select boxes: http://jsfiddle.net/bGDME/6/

And the updated JavaScript:

```
var $scopedSelects = $('#grade, #class').hide();
$('#scope').change( function(){
    var scopeLevel = $(this).val();
    $scopedSelects.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this[$this.data('scope-level') <= scopeLevel ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    });
});
```

The primary advantage this one might have is that the code stays the same regardless of how many "scoped selects" you have (assuming you update the initial selector, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple,

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("select[id!='scope'][id!='school']").hide();
    $('#scope').change( function(){
        $("select[id!='scope']").hide();
        var ken=$(this).val();
        $("#"+ken).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it a bit more dynamic by not touching the javascript when you want to add more select elements, then you can do small changes to your javascript code and HTML and you will only need to edit the HTML

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#scope').change(function() {
    var type = $(this).val().split(',');
    $('.values select').hide();
    for (x in type) {
        $('.values').find('#'+type[x]).show();
    }

});
```

});

HTML:

```
<select id='scope'>
<option value=''>Select</option>
<option value='school'>school</option>
<option value='school,grade'>grade</option>
<option value='school,grade,class'>class</option></select>
```